# Python 3.4 ImportError: No module named 'typing' when importing requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, importerror, python-3.4, python-pipelines

I've been trying to install different versions compatible for the **request** module for Python 3.4 (I know the python version is outdated, but is the one available for the OS I'm currently using.)

Using the `pip install requests==2.19.1` command worked without any problems.

The problem actually occurs when importing the requests module in the python shell. (also in a python script, the error appears)

**The line I execute:**

```py
>>> import requests
```

**The error:**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\user\project\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 112, in <modu
le>
    from . import utils
  File "D:\user\project\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "D:\user\project\lib\site-packages\requests\certs.py", line 15, in <module>
    from certifi import where
  File "D:\user\project\lib\site-packages\certifi\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

    from .core import contents, where
  File "D:\user\project\lib\site-packages\certifi\core.py", line 9, in <module>
    from typing import Union
ImportError: No module named 'typing'
```

I checked that I'm using the same environment where the request package was installed.

Comment: Can you show versions of installed packages? For example `python3 -m pip list` or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are importing from the package 'typing' but you do not have it installed. Try installing the package:

```
pip install typing
```

Answer (score 1):

Before trying the pip install typing (which it worked with the requests 2.19.1 version) I tried downgrading the requests module version to 2.12.1 and worked without the need to install typing.

But also barissonmez answer worked!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).